# Can I write a custom layer in tensorflow in python with existing ops such as conv2d and tensor operations?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

As stated in the title, I want to implement a custom layer in tensorflow with the existing ops and tensor operations. I wonder if I can do it in python just like what can be done in theano. In this layer, the input may be some matrices, the batch input and some weights and biases need to be learned. After some tensor operations, the output will be fed to the following layer. The computation in this layer may be complex, so I wonder if tensorflow can do auto-diff for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your layer is a composition of existing ops, it will just work, sure. That's how for example TF-Slim works.

```
# Skeleton code, just to demonstrate the concept
def conv(input, ...):
    kernel = tf.Variable(...)
    tmp = tf.nn.conv2d(input, kernel, ...)
    bias = tf.Variable(...)
    tmp = tf.nn.bias_add(tmp, bias, ...)
    return tf.nn.relu(tmp, ...)
```

defines a function that gives you an "integrated" layer which performs the usual steps of a basic convolution layer, which you then can use as

```
layer_1 = conv(input, ...)
layer_2 = conv(layer_1, ...)
```

and so on. As long as you're just composing ops that have gradients, the automatic differentiation will work.